# Whenever I start Android Studio, I get the following error message

Tags: android

> Gradle sync failed: CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not
>   compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your
>   computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit)
>   or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software
>   publisher

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the JDK location in your project structure:

Go to file -> project structure -> sdk location

Unselect 'Use embedded jdk (recommended)'

Then, change the JDK location to something like C/Program Files/java/jdk1.8,0_91

Comment: thank u and can you tell me why the mobile app not show in main activity